Dropbox demon suddenly stopped working (stuck starting forever) on two different Ubuntu machines (after restart, no changes)
My dropbox stopped syncing recently on two different linux machines
after restart. I spent hours trying to upgrade the first one before I
restarted the second one and noticed that it had the same problem. Both
stopped working after working fine for months or years. The first one
has been changed a lot since it stopped working, but I can report about
the second one.
I observed similar behaviour on the first machine before and after upgrading to ubuntu 24 (which I did before starting to debug much).
The main symptom is that Dropbox doesn’t sync. “dropbox status” returns
“Starting…” even for hours after typing “dropbox start”.
“dropbox start” produces a lot of messages about loading things, but rarely any warnings or errors. Occasionally it warns about fs.inotify.max_user_watches, but this seems bogus: I have only 13000 folders in my Dropbox and the default is 65536. Nonetheless, I increased my fs.inotify.max_user_watches to 200000. This does not make dropbox sync, and it does not always stop the message that I should increase it to 100000.
“dropbox stop” and “dropbox status” also tell me “DeprecationWarning: isSet()”.
I have successfully run “dropbox update” on both machines. Restarted the demon but problem was not solved.
I have also tried to install a .deb directly from Dropbox:
 $ sudo gdebi dropbox_2024.04.17_amd64.deb
/usr/bin/gdebi:113: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\S'
  c = findall("[[(](\S+)/\S+[])]", msg)[0].lower(
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree... Done
  Reading state information... Done
  Reading state information... Done
  This package is uninstallable
  Dependency is not satisfiable: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.40)
  )

Here is some more information:
 $  lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

 $ dpkg -l nautilus-dropbox
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name             Version              Architecture Description
+++-================-====================-============-========================>
ii  nautilus-dropbox 2019.02.14-1.2build2 amd64        Dropbox integration for >


I am now using Dropbox as a Flatpak rather than the deb version which always seemed troublesome in the past. ISTR that DB was always very slow in providing updates and there were problems with the systray icon suddenly disappearing. Can you still log in to your account in a browser with https://www.dropbox.com/home? The Flatpak version is 206.4.6506

Thanks! I can log in fine. The flatpak idea is new to me and seems a bit scary.

No need to worry. There's plenty of content on how to install Flatpak in Ubuntu and Debian based systems. I've been using the Flatpak version for some time now and it functions in exactly the same way (but without the issues). There's a useful guide from OMG Ubuntu here

Thanks. I'm not worried about tech, I'm worried about who I'm trusting.

as you will see from this Flathub page it's not verified by, affiliated with, or supported by Dropbox, Inc. but that is exactly the same position with the .deb version. From personal experience, I've not experienced any issues with it and the qualifying comment is mostly the case with many apps in the Flathub and snap store.

Thanks a lot. I did wind up installing flatpak and then installing the app. Unfortunately, I apparently have no idea what apps are, and couldn't figure it if it was running or how to use it. I have been using either dropboxd or nautilus-dropbox from the command line for quite a long time, and would really love to be able to get one of them to run again. I do greatly appreciate your help, and might come back to trying to figure out the app world when I have some time to do so.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
